# Scala RDD - Relaxing data aggregation based on criteria

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have data in this format :

```
RDD[(String, String, String), Int)]
```

Which I can represent it like this

```
|------|------|------------|----------------|
|(Month|Gender|Nationality)|NumberOfCustomer|
|------|------|------------|----------------|
| 1    |  M   |    FRA     |      8         |
| 1    |  F   |    FRA     |      2         |
| 1    |      |    FRA     |      2         |
| 1    |  M   |            |      7         |
| 1    |  F   |            |      2         |
| 1    |  M   |    USA     |      3         |
| 1    |  F   |    USA     |      4         |
| 1    |      |    USA     |      13        |
|------|------|------------|----------------|
```

Due to some constraints, I can't show data when there is less than **10** customers in it.
Hence I need to aggregate data by relaxing some criterias (*nationality* then *gender*).

For example since there is not enough (less than 10) Customers for the `Month 1 and the Gender M and the Nationality FRA`, I need to concatenate the data to the Nationality Other (Unknown).
After processing data, I should have something like this :

```
|------|------|------------|----------------|
|(Month|Gender|Nationality)|NumberOfCustomer|
|------|------|------------|----------------|
| 1    |  M   |  Other     |      15        |
|------|------|------------|----------------|
```

Same for `Month 1, Gender F and Nationality FRA`, then USA and so on.
The result should be :

```
|------|------|------------|----------------|
|(Month|Gender|Nationality)|NumberOfCustomer|
|------|------|------------|----------------|
| 1    |      |    FRA     |      2         |
| 1    |  M   |    Other   |      18        |
| 1    |  F   |    Other   |      8         |
| 1    |      |    USA     |      13        |
|------|------|------------|----------------|
```

After that, there is still not enough Customers for `Month 1, Gender Unknown and Nationality FRA`.
So I need to concatenate it with the `Month 1, Gender Unknown and the Nationality` with the least Customers in (here USA)
The result :

```
|------|------|------------|----------------|
|(Month|Gender|Nationality)|NumberOfCustomer|
|------|------|------------|----------------|
| 1    |  M   |    Other   |      18        |
| 1    |  F   |    Other   |      8         |
| 1    |      |    USA     |      15        |
|------|------|------------|----------------|
```

After that, there is still not enough Customers for `Month 1, Gender F and Nationality Other`.

I need to keep the `Month 1 - Gender Unknown - USA Nationality` (because there are more than 10 customers)
But I need to remove the Nationality criteria to `Month 1 - Gender F - Other Nationality` because there are only 8 customers in it.

The final final result should be

```
|------|------|------------|----------------|
|(Month|Gender|Nationality)|NumberOfCustomer|
|------|------|------------|----------------|
| 1    |Other |    Other   |      26        |
| 1    |      |    USA     |      15        |
|------|------|------------|----------------|
```

My question is how can I achieve this as efficiently as possible with Scala RDD in Apache Spark please ? (There are more than 2 criteria to relax, for example Nationality, then Gender, then Age, then Weight and so on, always in the same order)

***EDIT*** : Code and data added as asked in comment

To get my RDD[(String, String, String), Int)] :

```
val reducedByKey = myRDD.map(x =>
  (
    (
      x.month,
      x.gender,
      x.nationality
    ), 1
  )
).reduceByKey(_+_)
```

Some data :

```
((1,M,FRA),8)
((1,F,FRA),4)
((1,,FRA),46)
((1,M,ENG),13)
((1,F,ENG),40)
((1,M,USA),1)
((1,F,USA),4)
((1,,USA),3)
((2,M,FRA),4)
((2,F,FRA),1)
((2,M,USA),10)
((2,F,USA),4)
((2,,USA),60)
```

Comment: Can you add some data and code so that your question is reproducible?

Comment: @tuxdna I edited the question

Comment: Why after first aggregation customers count is 15?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan because I merged all Male with FRA nationality with all Male with Unknown nationality (8+7)

Comment: I had guessed so but the real question is whey 7 didn't get merged with 3 of USA? whats the logic that 7 get merged with 8 of FRA?

Comment: Because it was only for the first example, I realize it's messy and not clear you are right.
But in the second example, you can see 7-8-3 merged together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can be summarized as **changing the `Gender` and `Nationality` columns to `Other` when `NumberOfCustomer` column is less than 10**

So if you know of converting your `rdd` to `dataframe` as below

```
+-----+------+-----------+----------------+
|Month|Gender|Nationality|NumberOfCustomer|
+-----+------+-----------+----------------+
|    1|     M|        FRA|               8|
|    1|     F|        FRA|               4|
|    1|      |        FRA|              46|
|    1|     M|        ENG|              13|
|    1|     F|        ENG|              40|
|    1|     M|        USA|               1|
|    1|     F|        USA|               4|
|    1|      |        USA|               3|
|    2|     M|        FRA|               4|
|    2|     F|        FRA|               1|
|    2|     M|        USA|              10|
|    2|     F|        USA|               4|
|    2|      |        USA|              60|
+-----+------+-----------+----------------+
```

You can use the logic I explained above as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("Gender", when($"NumberOfCustomer" < 10, lit("Other")).otherwise($"Gender"))
  .withColumn("Nationality", when($"NumberOfCustomer" < 10, lit("Other")).otherwise($"Nationality"))
  .groupBy("Month","Gender","Nationality").agg(sum("NumberOfCustomer").as("NumberOfCustomer"))
  .show()
```

You should have your desired result

Comment: It helped me a lot, but to get the right result, I had to groupBy then aggregate after each WithColumn.
Thanks for the help !

Comment: I have used the groupBy and aggregation too in my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert data to a `DataFrame`:

```
val df = rdd.toDF.select(
  $"_1._1" as "month", $"_1._2" as "gender", $"_1._3" as "nationality", 
  $"_2" as "number_of_customers"
).na.replace(Seq("gender", "nationality"), Map("" -> "other"))
```

and apply cube with filter:

```
val aggregates = df
  .cube($"month", $"gender", $"nationality")
  .agg(sum("number_of_customers") as "number_of_customers")
  .where($"number_of_customers" >= 10)
```

This generates a number of sets:

```
+-----+------+-----------+-------------------+
|month|gender|nationality|number_of_customers|
+-----+------+-----------+-------------------+
| null|  null|        USA|                 20|
|    1| other|       null|                 15|
|    1| other|        USA|                 13|
|    1|  null|       null|                 41|
| null| other|        USA|                 13|
|    1|     M|       null|                 18|
| null|     M|       null|                 18|
| null|  null|        FRA|                 12|
| null|  null|       null|                 41|
| null| other|       null|                 15|
|    1|  null|        FRA|                 12|
|    1|  null|        USA|                 20|
+-----+------+-----------+-------------------+
```

You can later filter this result to for example find largest, non-overlapping sets of levels and aggregated results should be small enough to do it with standard set operations on local collections.

For example:

```
val sets = df
   .select(df.columns.map(c => concat_ws("_", lit(c), col(c))): _*)
    .collect.map(row => row.toSeq.collect { case s: String => s }.toSet )

sets.filter(s => !sets.contains(s subsetOf _)).foreach(println)
// Set(month_1, gender_M, nationality_FRA, number_of_customers_8)
// Set(month_1, gender_F, nationality_FRA, number_of_customers_2)
// Set(month_1, gender_other, nationality_FRA, number_of_customers_2)
// Set(month_1, gender_M, nationality_other, number_of_customers_7)
// Set(month_1, gender_F, nationality_other, number_of_customers_2)
// Set(month_1, gender_M, nationality_USA, number_of_customers_3)
// Set(month_1, gender_F, nationality_USA, number_of_customers_4)
// Set(month_1, gender_other, nationality_USA, number_of_customers_13)
```